# laravel group by with null value

Tags: php, laravel

I want a group by email and return latest from that record. that field could be null

here is my table structure is

```
full_name  |  email        | mobile | created_date
   van      | van@mail.com  | +1.... | 2018-03-07
   van L    | van@mail.com  | +12... | 2018-03-08
            |               | +11... | 2018-03-07
            |               | +11... | 2018-03-08
```

i want output as

```
full_name |  email        | mobile | created_date
            |               | +11... | 2018-03-08
   van L    | van@mail.com  | +12... | 2018-03-08
            |               | +11... | 2018-03-07
```

my code is

```
$byMobile =  User::Where('email',null)
         ->pluck('id','id')->toArray()

$byEmail = User::groupBy('email')
                ->orderByRaw("id DESC, created_at DESC")
                ->pluck('id','id')->toArray();

$user_ids = array_merge($byMobile, $byEmail);

$messageRequest = User::whereIn('id',$user_ids)
                    ->latest()->get();
```

can any one give me best method or query. i tried but i didn't get proper answer.. help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything? Edit the question to add what you've tried.

Comment: let me edit once

Comment: sql "group by" does not work as you wrote. it returns 1 record per value

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that

```
$byMobile   =   User::whereNull('email');

$messageRequest = User::whereNotNull('email')
                        ->union($byMobile)
                        ->groupBy('email')
                        ->orderByRaw("id DESC, created_at DESC")
                        ->get();
```

That is working for me I had the same problem.